# Read-only combo box in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

How to make a combo read-only?

I know how to make a text box read-only but it doesn't work for combos.

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you sure you have configured your combo box with the readOnly: true option?

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: true,
    readOnly: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    lazyRender:true,
    mode: 'local',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: [
            'myId',
            'displayText'
        ],
        data: [[1, 'item1'], [2, 'item2']]
    }),
    valueField: 'myId',
    displayField: 'displayText'
});
```

Comment: Good answer. For text boxes I said the read-only attribute on the EL. But that doesn't work for combo boxes.

Answer (score 7):

As @It Grunt says, you may want [`readOnly`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/TriggerField.html#cfg-Ext.form.TriggerField-readOnly). This makes the `ComboBox` act like a disabled textfield.

It's possible, however, that you mean [`editable: false`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/TriggerField.html#cfg-Ext.form.TriggerField-editable). This prevents you from typing text directly into the textfield -- you can change the selection however.